# radiobutton.checked always is false after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 3 **radiobutton** control and a submit **button** in my aspx page which are inside a **Content** control.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
     <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server">
          <asp:RadioButton ID="rd0" runat="server" GroupName="g1" Checked="true" />
          <asp:Image ID="img0" runat="server" ImageUrl="/image/img0.png" />
          <asp:RadioButton ID="rd1" runat="server" GroupName="g1" />
          <asp:Image ID="img1" runat="server" ImageUrl="/image/img1.png" />
          <asp:RadioButton ID="rd2" runat="server" GroupName="g1" />
          <asp:Image ID="img2" runat="server" ImageUrl="/image/img2.png" />
     </asp:Panel>
     <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
</asp:Content>
```

The user can select one of these radiobuttons and press submit button.
Now in code behind i want to diagnose which radiobutton is selected,

```
RadioButton checkedButton;
if (rd0.Checked)
   checkedButton = rd0;

else if (rd1.Checked)
   checkedButton = rd1;

else
   checkedButton = rd2;
```

but the checked property of all of the radiobuttons is false.

I have even set the checked property of the first radiobutton to true but it becomes to false after postback again.

Comment: add AutoPostBack="true" on your radio buttons

Comment: @Keram, I use jquery in this page and i want to do postback programmaticaly when the submit button is clicked, so i can not AutoPostBack property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this in your .cs:

```
Request.Form["YourRadioButton"]
```

Comment: Thanks @Kram for your quick reply.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have PostBack control in your Page_Load code section?

Try to add following code to your Page_Load event.

if(IsPostBack) return;